# WP_Query tax_query only returning posts that match first term

Tags: wp-query

I'm building a Wordpress shortcode and using arguments to build a WP_Query. So far this seems to be working and by defining multiple terms in the shortcode arguments these get passed onto the WP_Query as follows:

```
$args = Array
(
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => artist
        )

    [post_status] => publish
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => artist-medium
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => painting
                            [1] => metalwork
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This returns any posts that are in the 'painting' term, but not those that are in the 'metalwork' one. When I swap the order around then 'metalwork' posts are returned, but not 'painting'.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is your default `posts_per_page` number? Default operator for a `tax_query` is `IN`, you can verify this by looking at the SQL generated in `$your_query_object->request`.

Comment: The default posts_per_page was set as 10 in Settings>Reading. I don't think that could have been getting in the way but I've manually added `'posts_per_page'=>-1` to the $args array anyway as that would probably trip me up later on (so thanks for that).

This is the SQL:
`SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (32,35)
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`

Comment: I started working on something else but I'm back on this now. The SQL looks OK to me. It seems WP_Query has correctly converted the two term slugs into ids, but the results don't work. 
Can anyone tell what's happening here? It still only grabs posts that match the first term.